# How to reduce the database size of MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-sql

I have a website that runs on MS SQL Server 2014 Enterprise with two clustered virtual machines and AlwaysOn. A database backup is created each night and the size is now 20GB.

On my laptop, I also installed MS SQL Server 2014 Enterprise. I loaded the 20G database backup, and THEN create a backup copy. Interestly, this backup's size is about **3GB**. Why is there such a big difference? I really hope that the production setup also creates backups with similar size.

If I restore the database on the production with the 3GB backup from my laptop, do I lose anything? Any implications? Will I get 20GB nightly backups again? I have indexes on text fields of some tables. Nothing else special.

Note that I dont need the transaction logs. I dont need to revert the database back to a previous data point. I just want to reduce the backup size on the production server.

Thanks for any info!

Comment: "G" is not a size. "G" commonly means "generation" or refers to the numeric indicator "Giga". When giving us a size, use the correct terms "GB" or "Gb" so that we can clearly understand what you are talking about.

Comment: Also, you need Tlogs, and you need backups. To say otherwise is foolishness unless this site is entirely personal and you don't care if it disappears tomorrow without a trace.

Comment: Finally, what regular maintenance are you performing on the DB? MSSQL has built-in automated and regular maintenance which it can perform, including shrinking the DB. Have you set any of this maintenance up?

Comment: @music2myear, thanks for chimining in! I am sorry about the database size. It is GB, and I made corrections. This is a business website for a startup. Based on your info, seems I need to hire a professional for the work. Are you in the Washington, DC area? Interested in helping us out?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT, if you can post your two comments as an aswer, I will selet it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Process

On your "production" server from within [**SSMS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) go to **Server Properties > Database Settings** on this instance of **SQL Server** and ensure the **Compress database** option *is selected*. Next delete or rename the 20 GB backup file, and then rerun the full backup job again.

**NOTE:** *Be sure to delete the 20 GB SQL BAK file or rename it before you kick off the backup again after checking the **Compress database** option though or else you will not see the space saving.*

---

### Your Risks and Recovery Model Adjustments

Depending on your needs and what risks you (or your company) are willing to take with the data and what you are able to recover, transaction log backups may not be important—since you understand your data, risks, etc. only you'd know this importance.

Consider changing the DB [recovery model](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/4/sql-server-simple-recovery-model/) to **simple** and only do full DB backups and overwrite the existing backup per each run and do not append to the existing backup.

---

### Further Resource

- [SQL SERVER – Configure the Backup Compression](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/09/04/sql-server-configure-the-backup-compression-default-server-configuration-option/)